# Will replacing filament light bulbs with non-dimmable LED bulbs damage the bulbs and/or a dimmer?

Tags: lighting

I have replaced filament light bulbs with non-dimmable led bulbs using existing dimmer switch. This combination seams to work well. Will this damage the bulbs or the circuit.

Comment: The obvious/quick answer is "no"... But is there a specific reason you are asking -  are you concerned about something specific in your setup, like the use of the dimmer?

Comment: If it didn't matter they wouldn't make LEDs, or others, that were specifically "Dimmable".

Answer (score 4):

Yes, using non-dimmable lamps on a dimmer will eventually damage one or the other. Usually the lamps will suffer, specifically the driver in the LED.

Using the dimmer on full high should be OK, but you have to be careful to keep it that way.